# Preserving leading spaces in markdown

Tags: markdown

How can I preserve leading spaces in markdown without using code blocks. This is the sample text I'm working on:

```
                             Apache License
                       Version 2.0, January 2004
                    http://www.apache.org/licenses/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kramdown can do this

```
$ cat foo.md
<style>
.foo {
  text-align: center;
  white-space: pre;
}
</style>

{:.foo}
Apache License
Version 2.0, January 2004
http://www.apache.org/licenses/
```

Result

```
$ kramdown foo.md
<style>
.foo {
  text-align: center;
  white-space: pre;
}
</style>

<p class="foo">Apache License
Version 2.0, January 2004
http://www.apache.org/licenses/</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use non-breaking spaces

To preserve spaces in a Markdown document use a non-breaking space:
a space character that prevents consecutive whitespace characters from collapsing into a single space, and also prevents an automatic line break at its position.

**Example:**
   This line uses    non-breaking    spaces in many places; they   are not   collapsed.
   There is no need to use code blocks.

This line uses    many    consecutive spaces    in many places; they are all collapsed.

**Note:**
Copy and paste the previous example could not work because sometimes the non-breaking spaces are changed to normal spaces in a copy-paste operation :‑(.

The beauty of this solution is that you don't need to use any code in your Markdown document (in HTML you could use `&nbsp;`).

### How to introduce a non-breaking space?

- In macOS, you need to press    <kbd>⌥ Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>
- In Windows, sometimes work    <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> or  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>
- In many commercial software    <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

**PS:**
Reader, please, let us know in the comments is this method does not work in your particular markdown editor. I have tested this method in two apps and several online editors.